# Add a button on a point of zoomed image on Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, coordinates

I have to work on image that can be zoomed.
Once the image is zoomed the user can put a button on the exact point where he touched and that part is ok, but once the user re-zoomed the image at the initial state i want to button stay at the point of image not of the mobile display.
So, it's like i need to work on coordinates of pixel of image and not on coordinates of display, i can get the X and Y of touch but i can't associate them to the zoomed image.
I read some answer about that argument but no one works for my problem.

That is what i want to do:
[i open the image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POiwY.jpg)
[zoom on image and touch a point where add the button,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfrtT.jpg)
[this is i want to be the finanl result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3xSk.jpg)

If i didn't explain well, tell me something and i try to add some information, thanks!

```js
  relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                image.setOnPhotoTapListener(new OnPhotoTapListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPhotoTap(ImageView view, float x, float y) {
                        Log.d("coord2", "coordX2 is:" + x + ", coordY2 is:" + y);

                        Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                        btn.setText("test");

                        btn.setX(x);
                        btn.setY(y);

                        Log.d("coord3", "coordX3 is:" + btn.getX() + ", coordY3 is:" + btn.getY());
                        relativeLayout.addView(btn);
                    }
                });
                

                return false;
            }
        });
```

image is ImageView of the PhotoView library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry, i added it now

Answer (score 0):

To place a button on a specific point of a zoomed image and ensure that it stays at that point relative to the image (not the mobile display), you need to consider both the zoom factor and the position of the button. You can achieve this by using a custom ImageView and handling the touch event coordinates.

Here's a basic outline of how you can achieve this in Java in an Android application:

Create a custom ImageView that allows zooming. You can use libraries like PhotoView for this purpose.

Inside your custom ImageView, override the onTouchEvent method to capture the touch coordinates.

Adjust the coordinates based on the zoom factor to place the button correctly.

Create a button and add it to the layout, specifying the calculated coordinates.

Here's an example code snippet to illustrate the idea:

```
public class CustomZoomableImageView extends PhotoView {
    private Button button;

    public CustomZoomableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeButton(context);
    }

    private void initializeButton(Context context) {
        button = new Button(context);
        button.setText("My Button");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Handle button click here
            }
        });
        addView(button);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        // Adjust x and y based on the zoom factor
        Matrix matrix = getDisplayMatrix();
        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        float scaleFactor = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];

        float adjustedX = x / scaleFactor;
        float adjustedY = y / scaleFactor;

        // Set the button's position
        button.setX(adjustedX);
        button.setY(adjustedY);

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

In this example, CustomZoomableImageView is a custom ImageView that extends PhotoView (you can replace this with your zoomable view). It overrides onTouchEvent to capture touch coordinates and adjusts them based on the zoom factor. The button is created and positioned based on the adjusted coordinates.

Please note that this is a simplified example, and you may need to adapt it to your specific use case and layout. You also need to consider how to handle button placement and persistence when the image is re-zoomed.

Comment: i don't find the method getDisplayMatrix(), can you help me?